# lit-html : is there a way to force re-render of a template?

Tags: lit-html

I have been using as lit-html in my own custom web-component library.
I have third party webcompobent :

```js
html`<lottie-player src=${state.url}  background="transparent"  speed="1"  style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"  loop  autoplay></lottie-player>`
```

This third party components do not updates itself whenever `src` attribute is changed on it.  I understand, they have not designed it as such.

Is there a way to force lit-html to re-render this, as when I chnage the `state.url`, instead of deleting old node and creating new one, lit-html keep the same node intact and changes only its attribute.

If there a way to force re-render for this specific template each time ?

Comment: Are you using `lit-html` with `LitElement`? You could use `this.requestUpdate()` if so.

Comment: @pietrorea No I am not using LitElement. I am working with a custom lib on made on top of `lit-html`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I solved this issue by :

```js
let b = `<lottie-player src=${state.url}  background="transparent"  speed="1"  style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"  loop  autoplay></lottie-player>`;
t = html`${unsafeHTML(b)}`;
```

Concept: B is a string using plain template string. Then then use `unsafeHTML` directive to create a re-render it!

If any one has any better solution, will be glad to read it too.